# How to prevent Wi-Fi from disconnecting during a WhatsApp call?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, whatsapp-messenger

On the latest version of WhatsApp (2.16.133), the Wi-Fi keeps disconnecting during a voice call.

I suspect it's due to the screen going off ([here's a similar problem on the iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218354/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-dropping-wifi-connection-when-it-goes-to-sleep)), but it's just a wild guess.

Anyone knows a fix for this? I'm on Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Avast battery saver, uninstall it. It keeps disconnecting your wifi.